# Read multiple xml files from a .zip and store them in a list

Tags: r, xml2

I have many .xml files within a .zip archive. I wonder is it possible to read .zip file without unzipping in via read_xml and then store the result in a list (where each element would correspond to an .xml file)

Comment: No. Unzip the files, then read them. You could use `unzip()` to extract a subset of files.

Comment: @MrFlick 41, well in fact it is, just found a solution, will post it later!